# Are endowment plans better option than tax saving FD for last day tax saving investment?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, investing, india, tax-deduction

Its last day (31st March 2024) for investment in order to save tax. And I have not done anything !

Now I am planning to do some just to save tax. I am in 20% tax slab. Some options are closed for me for following reasons:

1. EPF - my UAB-aadhaar linking is screwed by pervious employer
2. PPF - also screwed by bank (forgot exact reason, but something like I accidently opened two PPF accounts and one of the account is locked, I barey have 500 INR in it)
3. ELSS - cant do investment on Sunday 31 March 2024. Also I dont want to do huge lumpsum investment in market linked option, especially when market is at higher leves.

So I  am exploring tax saving FDs vs guaranteed return / endowment plan. I know both are not great options at all, but my todays need is to save 20% tax which will be cut if I dont do any investment at all.

My doubt is:

**Q1.** Are endowment plans really good than tax saving FD? Do they provide better post tax return?

This is one of the illustration I found online: [image]

I know there are tax saving FDs with 7.1% return. But even with that, will endowment plan prove slightly better?

Also a side question,

**Q2.** can I do lumpsum investment in NPS on sunday / today / 31st March 2024?